# Center floated elements when one after the other

Tags: css, css-float

Is it possible to center floated elements.

```
<div>
 <div class="box">
 </div>
 <div class="box">
 </div>
</div>

.box {
float:left;
width: 600px;
}
```

When container div will have 1200 or more pixels div.box are near. When less, one after the other but I want center then.

I want to get:
[image: center]

Comment: You cannot do this using `float`, no

Comment: Do you need to float them? Otherwise `display:inline-block` on the boxes and `text-align:center` on the parent should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@media` tag for making it responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
//write your styles for screen size < 1200px here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 
    margin: 0 auto;
will work fine.
and also set your containers width in pixels.